# Git Error: bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: windows-10, bash, git, github, git-bash

When I open my GitBash (on Windows 10) I am getting the below error:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `date "+%D %X")'
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `__git_ps1 "(%s)")'
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error.  In my case my bash_profile had a line with __git_ps1 later followed by \n$.  I changed the \n$ to its ascii equivalent \012$ and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are doing command substitution, it should be like `$(date +%D %X)`

Comment: Thanks, but Sorry I am not using any command Substitution here. Initially, when I install and open the GitBash it's showing the above default comments.